# How to resolve "Crosstab has not printed anything on 3 consecutive pages, likely infinite loop"

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I am trying to create report in HTML form using Jasper report. It's creating .JRXML file. But while creating html file Jasper throws Exception

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Crosstab has not printed anything on 3 consecutive pages, likely infinite loop
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillCrosstab.prepare(JRFillCrosstab.java:557)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:388)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:347)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRHorizontalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRHorizontalFiller.java:2142)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRHorizontalFiller.fillGroupFooter(JRHorizontalFiller.java:994)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRHorizontalFiller.fillGroupFooters(JRHorizontalFiller.java:858)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRHorizontalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRHorizontalFiller.java:315)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRHorizontalFiller.fillReport(JRHorizontalFiller.java:144)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:903)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:832)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
at app.nova.power.util.PowerAnalysisUtil.getExportDataFile(PowerAnalysisUtil.java:803)
at app.nova.power.util.PowerAnalysisUtil.getExportFile(PowerAnalysisUtil.java:182)
at app.nova.power.actionimpl.DashBoardActions.executeAction(DashBoardActions.java:67)
... 159 more
```

This Exception comes when I have more columns in my report.

Here is my .JRXML file snippet

```xml
<group name="FakeSummaryGroup" isStartNewColumn="true">
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="0" isSplitAllowed="true"></band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="65" isSplitAllowed="true">
            <crosstab isRepeatColumnHeaders="false" isRepeatRowHeaders="false"
                columnBreakOffset="100000">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="9" y="10" width="409"
                    height="40" key="crosstab-1" />
                <crosstabParameter name="PROWS0" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PROWS0}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS0" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS0}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS1" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS1}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS2" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS2}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS3" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS3}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS4" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS4}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS5" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS5}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS6" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS6}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS7" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS7}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS8" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS8}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS9" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS9}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS10" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS10}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS11" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS11}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS12" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS12}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS13" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS13}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS14" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS14}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabParameter name="PCOLUMNS15" class="java.lang.String">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS15}]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabHeaderCell>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true"
                            isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"
                            hyperlinkTarget="Self">
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="264" width="10"
                                height="8" key="textFieldRowHeader -1" positionType="Float"
                                style="headerStyle" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"
                                isStyledText="false" lineSpacing="Single" markup="html">
                                <font fontName="" size="-1" />
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{PROWS0}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true"
                            isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"
                            hyperlinkTarget="Self">
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="10"
                                height="8" key="textFieldColumnHeader-1" positionType="Float"
                                style="headerStyle" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"
                                verticalAlignment="Top" isStyledText="false" lineSpacing="Single"
                                markup="html">
                                <font fontName="" size="-1" />
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS0}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true"
                            isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"
                            hyperlinkTarget="Self">
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="17" width="10"
                                height="8" key="textFieldColumnHeader-2" positionType="Float"
                                style="headerStyle" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"
                                verticalAlignment="Top" isStyledText="false" lineSpacing="Single"
                                markup="html">
                                <font fontName="" size="-1" />
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{PCOLUMNS1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
.
.
.
.
```

Please suggest me how do I resolve this Exception?
Didn't get any solution on google... :(

Thank You,
Navnath.

Comment: This exception indicates that the crosstab has not any rows. Did you pass the datasource (or connection) to crosstab?

Comment: Yes. I am passing datasource.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something like this also.
But I still don't have the solution.

The cause of this error is, you might have very long data (If printed will be more than 1 page) for one field.

CMIIW

Comment: "The cause of this error is, you might have very long data (If printed will be more than 1 page) for one field." Thanks for pointing that.